# Unable to cast object of type error in vb.net for a class created by xsd.exe

Tags: xml, vb.net, oop, xml-serialization, xsd.exe

I used xsd.exe to create a class "AnnualReturnA" from this schema:

http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema/forms/AnnualReturn-v2-6.xsd

I am struggling with how to implement the class. I have put my test procedure and relevant snippets of the class below.

My issue is that I get an error when executing the test procedure on line oAR.Officer(0) = AROfficer.Item(0) with error "Unable to cast object of type 'DirectorPersonType' to type 'AnnualReturnOfficer'".

Can anyone offer any advice on how to solve this error? I'm assuming I'm implementing the class incorrectly in my procedure but I don't know how else to do it. This is my first time using custom classes...

Test procedure:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim oAR As New AnnualReturnA.AnnualReturn
    Dim Add As New AnnualReturnA.UKAddressType
    Dim Add2 As New AnnualReturnA.UKAddressType
    Dim AROfficer As New AnnualReturnA.AnnualReturnOfficer
    Dim DirRetType As New AnnualReturnA.DirectorReturnType
    Dim DirPerType As New AnnualReturnA.DirectorPersonType

    oAR.CompanyCategory = AnnualReturnA.CompanyCategory.BYSHR
    oAR.MadeUpDate = #1/1/1999#
    ReDim oAR.Items(1)
    ReDim oAR.ItemsElementName(1)

    oAR.ItemsElementName(0) = AnnualReturnA.ItemsChoiceType.TradingOnMarket
    oAR.ItemsElementName(1) = AnnualReturnA.ItemsChoiceType.DTR5Applies

    oAR.Items(0) = True
    oAR.Items(1) = False

    ReDim oAR.SICCodes(1)

    oAR.SICCodes(0) = "4672"
    oAR.SICCodes(1) = "4783"

    Add.Postcode = "asdf"
    Add.CareofName = "Care Of"
    Add.Street = "strret"

    oAR.RegisteredOfficeAddress = Add

    Add2.Postcode = "sailasdf"
    Add2.CareofName = "sailCare Of"
    Add2.Street = "sailstrret"

    DirPerType.Forename = "Test Forename"
    DirPerType.Occupation = "Accountant"

    ReDim DirRetType.Item(1)

    DirRetType.Item(0) = DirPerType

    ReDim oAR.Officer(3)
    ReDim AROfficer.Item(3)

    AROfficer.Item(0) = DirRetType.Item(0)

    oAR.Officer(0) = AROfficer.Item(0)

    Dim xS As New XmlSerializer(oAR.GetType)
    Dim objStreamWriter As New StreamWriter("E:\testSerial.xml")
    xS.Serialize(objStreamWriter, oAR)
    objStreamWriter.Close()

End Sub
```

Officer:

```
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Officer")> _
    Public Property Officer() As AnnualReturnOfficer()
        Get
            Return Me.officerField
        End Get
        Set(value As AnnualReturnOfficer())
            Me.officerField = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

Annual Return Officer:

```
    Partial Public Class AnnualReturnOfficer

    Private itemField As Object

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Director", GetType(DirectorReturnType)), _
     System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Member", GetType(MemberReturnType)), _
     System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Secretary", GetType(SecretaryReturnType))> _
    Public Property Item() As Object
        Get
            Return Me.itemField
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            Me.itemField = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Director Return Type:

```
Partial Public Class DirectorReturnType

    Private itemField As Object

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Corporate", GetType(CorporateOfficerType)), _
     System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Person", GetType(DirectorPersonType))> _
    Public Property Item() As Object
        Get
            Return Me.itemField
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            Me.itemField = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Director Person Type:

```
Partial Public Class DirectorPersonType
    Inherits PersonBaseType

    Private serviceAddressField As ServiceAddressType

    Private dOBField As Date

    Private nationalityField As String

    Private occupationField As String

    Private countryOfResidenceField As String

    Private previousNamesField() As PreviousNameType

    Public Property ServiceAddress() As ServiceAddressType
        Get
            Return Me.serviceAddressField
        End Get
        Set(value As ServiceAddressType)
            Me.serviceAddressField = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

Comment: This is a casting problem, i.e. you're trying to set an orange equal to an apple. oAR.Officer(0) = Annual Return Officer, and your other item is not that type of object. You either need to create a new object of that (ARO) type, and set the values of it from AROfficer.Item(0) that you want. Then set that oAR.Officer(0) = new object.

Comment: (that's one possible solution)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can't get this at all. I thought DirRetType.Item(0) = DirPerType would cast the Director Person Type to a Director Return Type. Looking at it, as the item type is 'object' it just stores the old type. I don't know how to cast from the DirectorPersonType to a DirectorReturnType. I'll put this to one side and go back to basics